# Error when communicating with the native messaging host from extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to pass phonenumber from web page to desktop dialer. I have host, that catches phone number from page that passed from background.js:

```
var responseMessage = "";
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      console.log(request.phonenumber);
                chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('com.avvd.microsipcallfield', {text: request.phonenumber},function(response) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        responseMessage = chrome.runtime.lastError.message
        console.log(responseMessage);
    } else {
        responseMessage = response;
                }} )
      sendResponse(responseMessage);
  });
```

and sending it to host:

```
{
  "name": "com.avvd.microsipcallfield",
  "description": "Call Field Microsip host",
  "path": "C:\\Users\\All Users\\callFieldHost\\host.bat",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://lbhgehbjeemkjmooaeopmfljahdoombd/"
  ]
}
```

Host.bat

```
java -jar HostDecoder.jar %*
```

in general, for the time being there is no host, there will be an application that opens an object from JSON and sends it to the dialer. However
I wrote simple recorder and this is an output:

```
1argument: chrome-extension://lbhgehbjeemkjmooaeopmfljahdoombd/
2argument: --parent-window=0
```

While i try to send number i get in console
"Error when communicating with the native messaging host." and how we can see there is no number passed to host listener. 
Can somebody advice me to look for to repair this?

Comment: The message isn't sent as a parameter, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-host-protocol): your native host should use the standard stdin/stdout streams. See how it's implemented in the demos linked in the documentation

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did not read the documentation carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve issue. Trouble was in absent `@echo off` in launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. There is another question. I try to read incoming messages but get stability zero size.

```
private String read(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        byte[] length = new byte[4];
        in.read(length);
        int size = getInt(length);
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new InterruptedIOException("Zero size message");
        }

        byte[] message = new byte[size];
        in.read(b);

        return new String(message, "UTF-8");
    }

    private int getInt(byte[] bytes) {
        return  (bytes[3]<<24) & 0xff000000|
                (bytes[2]<<16) & 0x00ff0000|
                (bytes[1]<< 8) & 0x0000ff00|
                (bytes[0]<< 0) & 0x000000ff;
    }
```

I send with native message an object

```
{text: 4325345423}
```

What i miss in this case?